# Using java Streams with only one item as a computation context - good practice or not?

Tags: java, java-stream

Constantly i question myself if creating a `Stream` of one item is a good practice or a exploit of it's features. We're talking about code like this:

```
Stream.of(object)
    .map(this::doSomething)
    .map(this::doSomething)
    .findAny();
```

Like `Optionals`, `Streams` make it possible to implement more declarative code in Java, without the need to bind instructions as functions and compose then:

```
Function<x, y> doSomething = // some computation
Function<x, y> doSomethingElse = // other computation

doSomething.andThen(doSomethingElse).apply(object) // or using compose
```

The classic style of binding intermediary variables would produce code like this:

```
var x = doSomething(object)
var y = doSomethingElse(x)
```

While still completely valid and readable, using the stream construct we gain the freedom of composing several small functions sequentially - something that leads to better code on my opinion (it's easy to just plug new Function calls).

I could hack this as:

```
identity(Value.class)
    .andThen(this::doSomething)
    .andThen(something::execute)
    .andThen(this::doSomethingElse)
    .apply(value);
```

But i need a generic method like:

```
private <T> UnaryOperator<T> identity(Class<T> t) {
    return UnaryOperator.identity();
}
```

I can, of course, think of ways to reuse this code but i feel that there should be a better, native way of starting this function chain.

There's something native do Java or a better method to starting this function composing chain, without the need of binding a Function to a name?

Comment: why would you not use `Optional.of(...)` directly for single object?

Comment: Because i would be using `Optional` for a not optional value - a abuse, and i would need to use a `get` afterwards.

Comment: That's what `Optional.of` is for, indeed the docs on the method state : "Returns an {@code Optional} with the specified present non-null value" and "@throws NullPointerException if value is null". However you should use `Optional.ofNullable` which as the name suggests is  for a nullable object.  It is not abuse if used for its inteeded purpose?

Comment: The `ofNullable` constructor is intended to be used with a Maybe Null value - you're right. But that's not my scenario: my value is not null nor optional.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, this feels a bit overkill.
In the background a lot of objects get instantiated to accomplish such a simple task.
`Stream` is here to manage **streams of elements**.

Also

```
.findAny();
.findFirst();
```

aren't really *that* appropriate for the situation, mostly because they return an `Optional<T>` and you'll have to deal with it even if you know the result is always present.

On `Optional.of`, why `Optional`? I mean, there is nothing optional here, you know the value is there. It's misleading. Use `Optional` once in the wrong place and you'll have it all over the place.

There is nothing wrong in having multiple consecutive method calls that create an object `B` starting from an object `A`.
The key points are **immutability** and **intermediate state**. Just use immutable definitions and you'll be okay.

Remember Java isn't functional-first (still).

---

Anyway, you might be interested in [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or [FunctionalJava](https://www.functionaljava.org/).

Comment: Exactly, since i've put a single item inside a `Stream`, there's two easy options to 'take it out': with a `Collector` or a `Optional`. Both are overkill and smell of exploitation (as you said, most of the times there will be nothing optional there). Thanks for your input! I've checked RxJava in the past, but FunctionalJava is something new. Will totally check it out!

Comment: @MiguelFontes It's nothing. I'd say, keep things as simple as possible as a general rule. Functional programming is not the end of the world ;)